# Regex length check account for optional group

Tags: javascript, regex

```
export const validUKPhone = /^(\+)?(44)?(\s*\d){9,11}$/;
```

I currently have the following RegEx for a telephone number, that is trying to validate the length of a number.

Now the fun bit of this, is that there are 3 optional characters at the start of the pattern. +44 (potentially).

My question is how to write my regex to take account for this group, and only count the length of the 'main body' of the number. If the +44 exists, the length pattern would be `{12,14}` otherwise `{9,11}`

e.g. The following test fails.

```
  expect(regex.test('+440798444')).toBeFalsy();
  expect(regex.test('+440798444457')).toBeTruthy();
```

(10 characters currently because of the +44 but returns true)

Comment: `0798444` is 7 digits, you require at least 9.

Comment: I think you want: `^(?:.{3})?\+?(44)?\d{9,11}$`

Comment: Try `/^(?:\+?44\s*\d|(?!44))(?:\s*\d){9,11}$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this is close - as it continues to honour the requirement for spaces which you spotted in the original regex, but fails this  expect(regex.test('+44079251345672')).toBeFalsy(); presumably something to do with the + character

Comment: You say there can be additional 12, 13 or 14 digits if the number starts with `44`. Why is `+44079251345672` false? `079251345672` is 12 chars long.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the requirement is 9 to 11 characters irrespective of whether +44 is there or not, so the 079251345672 fails because 12 characters. My question is probably poorly worded, but I just want the length pattern to ignore +44 if it exists.

e.g.

 expect(regex.test('+440798444')).toBeFalsy();
expect(regex.test('+4407925134567')).toBeTruthy();
expect(regex.test('+44079251345672')).toBeFalsy();
expect(regex.test('07925134567')).toBeTruthy();
expect(regex.test('123456789112')).toBeFalsy();

Comment: Ah, so `/^(?:\+?44|(?!\s*4\s*4))(?:\s*\d){9,11}$/`? `/^(?:\+?44|(?!44))(?:\s*\d){9,11}$/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes. you beautiful man. That's it! stick as an answer to receive the beautiful stackoverflow karma nectar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?:\+?44|(?!44))(?:\s*\d){9,11}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkIIlH/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\+?44|(?!44))` - a non-capturing group matching:

  - `\+?44` - an optional `+` and then `44`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!44)` - (a negative lookahead that matches) a location that is not immediately followed with `44` (add `\s*` if you do not want to match the number even if there are whitespaces before/inside `44`)
- `(?:\s*\d){9,11}` - nine to eleven occurrences of zero or more whitespaces and then a digit
- `$` - end of string.